# Я когда приду(,) позвоню тебе

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли в этих предложениях запятая? Я думаю, что только в 1-м нужна, т. к. в нём нет второй части союза – *-то*.

1. Я когда приду(,) позвоню тебе.
2. Я когда приду(,) то позвоню тебе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Указанная запятая нужна в обоих случаях.
Наличие второй части союза влияет на постановку запятой **перед** придаточным предложением. Это рассматривается в теме «[**Постановка запятой при встрече союзов**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188)» (Грамота.ру).
В данных предложениях нет встречи союзов, но, думаю, здесь тоже можно применить эти правила.

1. *Я, когда приду, позвоню тебе.* (Придаточное можно переставить или изъять без нарушения структуры главного предложения.)
2. *Я когда приду, то позвоню тебе.*

**P. S.** В первом случае запятая перед «когда» может не ставиться. Это зависит от задумки автора, интонации (наличия/отсутствия паузы, вставочного характера), контекста. А вот запятая после придаточного ставится всегда, независимо от «то».

Comment: Саша, а ты не рассматриваешь вариант с инверсией? Обычная (прямая) последовательность такая: *Когда я приду, позвоню тебе*. А если разговорная речь, просто с перестановкой союза? Возможно ведь... *Тут на двери защелочка есть, так ты ее накинь… **Я когда приду, постучусь** вот так – ты и откроешь…* (сборник).

Comment: Вот ещё: *– А сейчас мы пойдём за грибами! – сказал Боря. – А ты лежи и лечись. **Я когда приду, почитаю** тебе книжку* (А. Горбатова) .

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, я думал об этом. Честно говоря, запятая "не смотрится". Но если задумывалась остановка / пауза / вставочная интонация, то запятая даст это понять и прочитать соответственно.